# Create domain model in Ruby that adds students to a school roster

Tags: ruby, model

You should be able to add a student to the school by calling the add_student method and giving it an argument of the student's name and their grade.

Let's say that we're adding the student "AC Slater" to grade 9. If the roster already has a key of grade 9, we'll be able to push AC Slater into the array that the grade 9 key points to. Otherwise, we'll need to first create the key of grade 9 and point it to an empty array. However, if we're in the scenario in which the grade 9 key already exists, we will erase its current contents by creating a key of 9 and setting it equal to an empty array!

Desired Behavior:

```
school.add_student("AC Slater", 9)
school.add_student("Kelly Kapowski", 10)
school.add_student("Screech", 11)
school.roster
# => {9 => ["Zach Morris", "AC Slater"], 10 => ["Kelly Kapowski"], 11     => ["Screech"]}
```

What I have so far:

```
class School
  attr_accessor :roster, :student_name, :school_name
  def initialize(school_name)
    @school_name = school_name
    @roster = {}
  end

  def add_student(student_name, grade)
    if @roster[grade] == true
      @roster[grade] << student_name
    else
      @roster[grade] = []
      @roster[grade] << student_name
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` condition of your `add_student` method: `if @roster[grade] == true` is actually never going to work the way you think it would because when you access a Hash with a key which does not exist it returns `nil`, otherwise the value.

When key does not exist:

```
@roster = {}
@roster[9] #=> nil
```

while for an existing key value will be returned:

```
@roster = { 9 => ["AC Slater"] }
@roster[9] #=> ["AC Slater"]
```

So, when the key exist you compare `if ["AC Slater"] == true`, which is, of course, a false condition, hence your code always executes `else` condition. Hence, you always end up with only one value for a grade in your `@roster` hash.

A small change will make it work:

```
def add_student(student_name, grade)
  if @roster[grade]
    @roster[grade] << student_name
  else
    @roster[grade] = []
    @roster[grade] << student_name
  end
end
```

---

However, if you don't like such conditions like I do. You can [pass a block](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) to `@roster` which stores a default array for a key in hash when it is being `initialized`:

```
def initialize(school_name)
  @school_name = school_name
  @roster = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }
end
```

This block now will be executed every time you try to fetch a key when the key does not exist, it creates an empty array for it, otherwise, returns the value. So, you can now safely change your `add_student` method to this:

```
def add_student(student_name, grade)
    @roster[grade] << student_name
end
```